# XPath position / second city visited in August

Tags: xpath

I have this code

```
<vacaciones>
    <destino identificador="m036" tipo="unico">
        <ciudad>Palma de Mallorca</ciudad>
        <fecha_salida>
            <dia>22</dia>
            <mes>Abril</mes>
        </fecha_salida>
    </destino>

    <destino identificador="i07" tipo="pack">
        <ciudad>Milán</ciudad>
        <ciudad>Florencia</ciudad>
        <fecha_salida>
            <dia>13</dia>
            <mes>Agosto</mes>
        </fecha_salida>
    </destino>

    <destino identificador="a456" tipo="unico">
        <ciudad>Amsterdam</ciudad>
        <fecha_salida>
            <dia>17</dia>
            <mes>Agosto</mes>
        </fecha_salida>
    </destino>
</vacaciones>
```

And they ask me about the expression for "The second city visited in those destinations starting in August."

I'm not sure either if they are talking about Florencia or Amsterdam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three destinations : Spain, Italy, Netherlands. Only one with two cities visited in August, just before the third Amsterdam. So yes, i suppose it's Florencia.

Shortest form :

```
//destino[2]/ciudad[2]/text()
```

Longest form with conditional expression :

```
//destino[count(./ciudad)>1][.//mes[.="Agosto"]]/ciudad[2]/text()
```

**EDIT** : Explanations :

- // means anywhere in the document.
- . means self (ie ~ "starting this point")
- [2] means the second element

So if i translate in words what i've posted :

Look anywhere in the document for a destino tag (//destino) which have to fit these conditions (the brackets [])

- contain more than 1 "ciudad" child tag ([count(./ciudad)>1])
- contain somewhere (//) a "mes" tag entitled "Agosto" [.//mes[.="Agosto"]

Once we have found a destino tag which fits the condition we get the second "ciudad" child tag (/ciudad[2]) and retrieve its content (/text()).

Comment: Thanks, this was the correct answer! :D Just a question: how did you get this result? I don't undersant the . or the // or the [2] or the text()

Comment: OK. Post is edited. I wrote in XPath language what you were looking for. Mark my answer as accepted if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do it with more code and not only with Xpath's unless you are sure that "destinos" come ordered by date (...)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what those who asked you the question were really after...

```
//ciudad[following-sibling::fecha_salida//dia=max(//ciudad[following-sibling::fecha_salida//mes='Agosto']/following-sibling::fecha_salida//dia) ]/text()
```

Output:

> Amsterdam

Three cities were visited in August, the first two on the 13th and the third, Amsterdam, on the 17th. So the 17th is the 2nd visit date in August. The expression above looks for a city visited in August, and which has a visit date which is the latest (highest or `max()`) of the dates in that month, and selects the name of that city.

As an aside, it would have been far clean to do it using xquery, but that's another story.